# Applying user patterns in pytesseract

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using pytesseract to try to detect certain pattern of strings in images.
As far as I understand, the correct use of `user patterns` will help pytesseract make a better scan for a certain pattern of string. However, I can't figure out how to put that to work. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847859/pytesseract-using-user-patterns) helps clarifying that to use I must use the `config` argument (pytesseract.pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='), but I didn't get how to apply that to my case.

I'm trying to find this regex pattern: `\d{5}\.?\d{5} \.?\d{6} ?\d{5}\.?\d{6} ?\d ?\d{14}`. How should I apply that in `user patterns` to help tesseract make a better OCR scanning?

Answer (score 4):

It is a little hard to find it.
Yes,the `user-pattern` in `tesseract` couldn't work well in the old version of `tesseract`.

Refer to [this Pull Request on github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/pull/2328).

And finally I found the example of how to use the `user-pattern` in `tesseract`.In your circumstance,you could try:

1. Firstly, make sure the version of `tesseract` >= 4.0.(I recommend you install `tesseract` 5.x,because I used 5.x in my PC)
2. Create a file called `xxx.patterns`.The content(with **UNIX** line endings (line-feed character) and a **blank line** at the end):

```
\d{5}\.?\d{5} \.?\d{6} ?\d{5}\.?\d{6} ?\d ?\d{14}
```

3. Then try to use:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string("test.png", config="--user-patterns yourpath/xxx.patterns")
```

---

Finally, it worked for me(This is an example in documentation.):
[image]

---

Also you could refer to this [documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/APIExample-user_patterns).

Comment: Thanks @jizhihaoSAMA. Do you know if applying user patterns helps the pytesseract AI to find those patterns or that's simply an embeded regex?

Comment: @abutremutante Not sure,But I think it should.

Comment: the my.patterns should be a file of what format? txt?

Comment: @abutremutante On my PC, I create a txt, and rename it as `xx.patterns`.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but I faced a similar problem with tesseract a few months ago. You might want to take a look at whitelisting, more specifically, whitelisting all digits. Like this,

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(question_img, config="-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789. -psm 6")
```

This however did not work for me, so I ended up using opencv knn, this does mean you need to know where each char is located though... First I stored some images of the characters I wanted to recognize. And added those detections to a temporary file:

```
frame[y:y + h, x:x + w].copy().flatten()
```

After labeling all those detections I trained them using the previously mentioned knn.

```
network = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()
network.train(data, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, labels)
network.save('pattern')
```

Now all chars can be analysed using.

```
chars = [
    frame[y1:y1 + h, x1:x1 + w].copy().flatten(), #char 1
    frame[y2:y2 + h, x2:x2 + w].copy().flatten(), #char 2
    frame[yn:yn + h, xn:xn + w].copy().flatten(), #char n
]

output = ''
network = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()
network.load('pattern')
for char in chars:
    ret, results, neighbours, dist = network.findNearest([char.astype(np.float32)], 3)
    output = '{0}'.format(result)
```

After this you can just do your regex on your string. Total training and labeling only took me something like 2 hours so should be quite doable.

Answer (score 0):

TesseractOCR doesn't support regex expressions. Patterns use their proprietary format for pattern recognition, which is a much diminished subset of regex syntax.
see:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/main/src/dict/trie.h
above: 'read_pattern_list()'